# I have 2 SQL queries and I need to combine them together in one piece

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with combining two queries which gives out different results into one functional query.

```
use DBname
select tblComputer.HostName, 
    tblComputer.Manufacturer, 
    tblComputer.Model, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorType, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorCount, 
    tblComputerHardware.CoreCount, 
    tblInstances.InstanceName
from tblDatabases 
    JOIN tblComputer ON tblDatabases.ComputerID=tblComputer.ComputerID 
    join tblComputerHardware ON tblComputer.ComputerID=tblComputerHardware.ComputerID 
    join tblInstances ON tblComputer.ComputerID=tblInstances.ComputerID 
where IsVirtual=0
```

So this query gives out results which I defined from couple of tables. Now I want to add one more column in which I will have Instances installed on each computer. Note that there are multiple instances on one computer and I need those instances to be seperated with ",". I have found that this query works for me

```
select tblInstances = STUFF((
    select ',' + InstanceName
    from tblInstances
    for xml path ('')
    ), 1, 1, '')
```

But I`ve been struggling on how to combine theese two queries in one so that I would be able to see multiple instances seperated with comma on each computer.

Im hoping for help from you guys and I hope that you will understand my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lateral subquery. I've *assumed* that you've used `FOR XML PATH` intentionally because you're on SQL Server 2016 or prior, and so have also used that. If you are on 2017+ then you probably want to look into `STRING_AGG`. I have, however, switched to using `TYPE` and `text()` as the former won't escape special characters, and the latter is more performant:

```sql
SELECT C.HostName, 
       C.Manufacturer, 
       C.Model, 
       CH.ProcessorType, 
       CH.ProcessorCount, 
       CH.CoreCount, 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + I.InstanceName
              FROM tblInstances I
              WHERE I.ComputerID = C.ComputerID
              FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS InstanceNames --Use nvarchar if needed
FROM tblDatabases D --Use Aliases, it makes your code far more succinct
    JOIN tblComputer C ON D.ComputerID = C.ComputerID 
    JOIN tblComputerHardware CH ON C.ComputerID = CH.ComputerID 
WHERE C.IsVirtual = 0;  --Alias guessed
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this ?

```
select tblComputer.HostName, 
    tblComputer.Manufacturer, 
    tblComputer.Model, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorType, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorCount, 
    tblComputerHardware.CoreCount, 
    string_agg(tblInstances.InstanceName, ',') as Instances
from tblDatabases 
    JOIN tblComputer ON tblDatabases.ComputerID=tblComputer.ComputerID 
    join tblComputerHardware ON tblComputer.ComputerID=tblComputerHardware.ComputerID 
    join tblInstances ON tblComputer.ComputerID=tblInstances.ComputerID 
where IsVirtual=0
group by tblComputer.HostName, 
    tblComputer.Manufacturer 
    tblComputer.Model, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorType, 
    tblComputerHardware.ProcessorCount, 
    tblComputerHardware.CoreCount
```